# Value of a register after the following commands

Tags: assembly, endianness, riscv

I have the following code in front of me and need to determine what is the value of `x12` will be at the end.

The code:

```
addi x11,x0,0x3f5
sw x11,0(x5)
lb x12,1(x5)
```

I think that after the first command, `x11` will contain `00 00 03 f5` in hexadecimal representation.

After the second command, `x5` is supposed to contain exactly the same thing, `00 00 03 f5`.

Then when `lb` is done, we are supposed to skip a single byte of `x5` but that still gives us `00` and after all I don't understand why `x12` won't contain `00 00 00 00`.

The correct value is 0x3, or `00 00 00 03`. What is my mistake?

Comment: That's because riscv is little endian. As such the byte order in memory is `f5 03 00 00`.